# Kubernetes PV/PVC not mounting to the correct volumeMounts in the pods

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I'm running into a weird issue with my newer deployments where volumes aren't mounting correctly.

Example..

There are PV/PVCs for three NFS directories that relate to one deployment:

- NFS/in
- NFS/out
- NFS/config

In the deployment, those PVCs mount to the corresponding volumeMounts

- volumeMounts/in
- volumeMounts/out
- volumeMounts/config

With my older deployments, this works as expected.  With the new deployments, the NFS directories are mounting to the incorrect mount points...  The contents of NFS/in are mounted in volumeMounts/config.  NFS/config are mounted in volumeMounts/in.

This is vanilla Kubernetes on a bare metal node.  The only configuration change from default that has been made was yanking PVC protection due to PVCs not being deleted on request:

```
kubectl patch pvc PVC_NAME -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers": []}}' --type=merge
```

Any ideas on what causes the directories to mount in the incorrect volumeMounts?

Comment: Might be hard to identify without seeing exact resource YAMLs. Blind guess - anyhow related to type of storage class chosen?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set ClaimName though your deployment or statefulset :

```
...
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
.......
   containers:
      - name: container-name
        image: container-image:container-tag
        volumeMounts:
        - name: claim1
          mountPath: /path/to/directory
   volumes:
      - name: claim1
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: PVC_NAME
...
```